# Selenium Proxy Pop up in Java

Tags: java, selenium, url, proxy, connection

Everything is working completely fine except this one proxy login which I can’t bypass.

Here is what I've tried to pass this:

https://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@url - This still displays the same popup

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(proxy.getUsername()); // Alert is never found.
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(proxy.getUsername()); // Nothing happens
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(proxy.getUsername()).build().perform(); // Nothing is happening
```

Here is the code I'm using to connect to the url

```
    public void execute(ProxyConnection proxy) {
        WebDriver driver = setupDriver(proxy);
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // Here I use test methods like shown above
    }

    public WebDriver setupDriver(ProxyConnection proxyConnection) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "MY PATH");

        String proxyadd = proxyConnection.getHostName() + ":" + proxyConnection.getPort();
        
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyadd);
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxyadd);
        
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
        
        if (!debugMode) {
            options.addArguments("--headless");
        }

        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

I'm using ChromeDriver version: 91.0.4472

I'm using selenium-chrome-driver version: 3.8.0

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Still no answer to this.

I even tried playing around with selenium and chrome versions but still no luck. I updated to BETA v4.0.0 and this didn't have any effect.

AutoIT or Robot is not suitable because it needs to be headless.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username");

You find more exemples in https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html

Comment: Get this error when using that:
`Exception in thread "Timer-0" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert`

Comment: You consider autoit to use? Because in the past the item #2 of this topic worked for me https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/handling-login-popup-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java/

Comment: Is there another way I can do it rather than using third-party software? Could it be an issue with my driver versions?

Comment: Also, would AutoIT work with a headless browser? Because my application would need to be able to run without a user interface

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering what the solution was because I was testing for hours and hours but finally found one that works...

```
((HasAuthentication) driver).register(UsernameAndPassword.of(ProxyData.getInstance().getUsername(), ProxyData.getInstance().getPassword()));
```

Note: This requires version Selenium 4.0.0 or higher.